# Store TinyGPS++ latitude value into a variable of type string or float

Tags: arduino-mega, gps, tinygps, float

I want to get the GPS ordinates in degrees with 6 decimal accuracy. I can obtain this by creating a gps object with TinyGPS library. but In the TinyGPS example codes, its written

```
Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);
```

But I actually want to store this latitude degrees in a variable of type string or float. when i write this;

```
double Tiny_latitude = (gps.location.lat());
Serial.print("Tiny lat:");
Serial.println(Tiny_latitude);
```

it returns me Tiny lat:33.55 on serial monitor. But i want 33.546600.
How do I do that ?

Comment: "double lat = gps.location.lat();" but I think there is more to this question?

Comment: double and float , both are not working. both giving me 33.55 as an answer. check my updated question ...

Comment: double and float are the same on AVR. The answer to the number of decimals printed is here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print. The default is two.

Comment: Try Serial.println(Tiny_latitude, 6); But remember the max number of digits is 6-7. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Float

Comment: O man, You're a life saver ! Thanks a bunch :) Serial.println(Tiny_latitude, 6); worked like charm.

Comment: One last thing, Now if i want to make a String "your location is \nlat:33.546600 \nlong: 75.456912" ,  i.e. my String variable are stored in Tiny_latitude and Tiny_longitude and want to make a string my_Location. How do i do that ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it returns me Tiny lat:33.55 on serial monitor. But i want 33.546600. How do I do that?

The issue is simply the number of decimal places. That can be added to the Serial.println().

```
double Tiny_latitude = (gps.location.lat());
Serial.print("Tiny lat:");
Serial.println(Tiny_latitude, 6);
```

> Now if i want to make a String "your location is \nlat:33.546600 \nlong: 75.456912" , i.e. my String variable are stored in Tiny_latitude and Tiny_longitude and want to make a string my_Location. How do i do that?

I would use sprintf() for that but as that requires some additional build parameters the easiest way is to use String. Some special care is needed to increase the number of decimal places.

```
void loop() 
{ 
  ...
  float latitude = 33.546600;
  float longitude = 75.456912;
  String buf;
  buf += F("your location is \nlat:");
  buf += String(latitude, 6);
  buf += F("\nlong:");
  buf += String(longitude, 6);
  Serial.println(buf);
  ...
}
```

Cheers!